# Rails faye server won't start

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, faye

I have an Rails application which I am attempting to include the `faye` ruby gem.
I have installed `faye` with

```
gem install faye
```

and added a faye.ru to my root rails app. folder:

```
require 'faye'
Faye::WebSocket.load_adapter('thin')
faye_server = Faye::RackAdapter.new(:mount => '/faye', :timeout => 45)
run faye_server
```

When I want to start faye with:

```
rackup -s thin -E production config.ru
```

I only get:

```
`require': cannot load such file -- faye
```

How do I address this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include it in your `Gemfile`:

```
gem 'faye'
```

Then run `bundle install`, this make the gem available to your application.

Also consider `gem 'faye', require: 'faye'` to make the loaded gem available to your entire application.

Comment: @phil no problem... You should check out the book [Agile Web Development with Rails](http://pragprog.com/book/rails4/agile-web-development-with-rails), the way you are approaching the _development_ of your rails app is making it _way_ more difficult than it is supposed to be (putting files into the root of your app, testing in a production environment, loading library/gems directly into the files of the app, etc.... basically not having to do these types of things is exactly why people use rails).

Answer (score 0):

`require 'rubygems'` on the top of your `faye.ru` (before the `require 'faye'`) will probably resolve this.

Comment: Since Ruby 1.9 this library is automatically loaded.

Answer (score 0):

For my case, just add `bundle exec` before the command and it worked.

`bundle exec rackup faye.ru -E production -s thin`